# Whats the difference between C# delegates, Dynamic Proxy, Closures and function pointers?

Tags: language-agnostic, delegates, closures, function-pointers, dynamic-proxy

What are useful definitions for the common methods of passing a method or function as data, such as:

- Delegates
- Closures
- Function pointers
- Invocation by dynamic proxy and
- First class methods?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Function pointers** lets you pass functions around like variables. Function pointer is basically legacy method to pass function around in languages that don't support first-class methods, such as C/C++.

**First class methods** Basically means you can pass functions around like variables. Methods (loosely) mean functions. So this basically means *first class functions*. In simplest terms, it means functions are treated as "first class citizens", like variables. In the old days (C/C++), because we can't directly pass a function around, and we had to resort to workarounds like function pointers, we said functions weren't first-class citizens.

**Delegates** is C#'s answer to first-class methods. Delegates are somewhat more powerful because it involves *closures*, consider the following code snippet:

```
void foo( int a )
{
   void bar() { writefln( a ); }
   call( &bar );
}

void call( void delegate() dg  ) { dg(); }
int main( char[][] args ) {
   foo( 100 );
}
```

Notice that `bar` can reference the local variable `a` because delegates can use closures.

**Closures** can be very confusing at first. But the lazy-man's definition can be really simple. It basically means a variable can be available in the human-expected way. Put in other words, a variable can be referenced in places where they look like they would be present, by reading the structure of the source code. For example, looking at the code fragment above. If we didn't have closure, `bar` would not be able to reference `a` because `a` was only local to `foo`, but not `bar`, which is another function.

**Dynamic Proxy** is the odd one out. It doesn't belong to these items. Explaining it requires some very long text. It stems from the famous [Proxy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). The problem with Proxy Pattern was that the Proxy class needs to be implementing the same interface as the Subject. Dynamic Proxy basically means using reflective approach to discover the Subject's method so that the ProxyPattern can be freed from being tied to the Subject's interface.

Answer (score 0):

just the ones i know about:

- Function pointers:  just that, a pointer to a piece of code.  you jump to it, it executes.  typed languages can enforce some parameter passing convention (i.e. C declarations)
- Closures: a function with some state paired.  most naturally written in lexically scoped languages (i.e. Scheme, JavaScript, Lua). several closures can share the same state (or part of it), making it an easy way to implement OOP.
- First class methods: a closure created from an object instance and a method.  some languages with both closures and a native OOP (Python, JavaScript) can create closures automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Closure is a programming language concept. Delegate is its realization in MS.NET.

A Delegate in MS.NET is a strongly typed pointer to an object's method (a delegate instance points to both - an object and its method). There is also a way to combine several void delegate instances into one.